# Find number of pairs in an array whose sum is divisible by k

Tags: algorithm

I was doing a CodeSignal practice, and I had the following question:

> You are given an array of integers a and an integer k. Your task is to calculate the number of ways to pick two different indices i < j, such that a[i] + a[j] is divisible by k. The constraints are: 1 ≤ a.length ≤ 10^5, 1 ≤ a[i] ≤ 10^9, 1 ≤ k ≤ 10^9.

For a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and k = 3, the answer should be 4.

I found a solution that uses buckets and could be done in O(n) time, or specifically just a single pass:

```py
def solution(a, k):  
    buckets = [0 for _ in range(k)]
    res = 0
    for num in a:
        mod_value = num % k
        res += buckets[(k - mod_value) % k]
        buckets[mod_value] += 1
    return res
```

But I was getting a time limit exceeded (9/11 test cases passed). I thought it was a Python issue, so I tried implementing the same solution in Java but I got hit with a runtime error. Investigating with a custom test case with `k = 10^9` resulted in an out of memory error, suggesting the failing test cases were for extreme input values.

I am not sure if there is an even better solution, or if this problem is bugged on CodeSignal's side.

Comment: Did you try a hash map instead of buckets, (which is a perfect hash map, but potentially very large.)

Comment: k can be as large 10^9 so your buckets in line 1 is going to contain 1 billion elements.  This is going to cause a timeout to create.   Try a better representation of buckets.

Comment: Can you use numpy? I would try something like `buckets = numpy.zeros(k)` if the problem is time limit exceeded.

Comment: Don't try to make a billion row numpy array, try with a dict instead.

Comment: You will be using at most 10^5 indexes of the array, so 1/10000 of the allocated memory, a hash map has usually a load factor of roughly 3/4.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use a hash table instead of a bucket/array. Since there could be a lot of empty slots in the bucket if `k` can be 10^9, and your memory can grow to ~1GB. If you use a hash table, your memory is restricted to your input size `n` at most, which you assume it is much smaller than 10^9.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```py
import collections

def solution(a, k):
    store = collections.defaultdict(list)
    total = 0

    for i in range(len(a)):
        complement = (k - a[i] % k) % k
        total += len(store[complement])
        store[a[i] % k].append(i)

    return total
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler version using ints instead of lists

```
   from collections import defaultdict
    def solution(a, k):
        if len(a) < 2:
            return 0
        count = defaultdict(int)
        res = 0
        for i, num in enumerate(a):
            complement = (k - num % k) % k
            res += count[complement]
            count[num % k] += 1
        return res
```